# Push new property to the current object inside a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

In my script, I make to async get to obtain data for my object.

Here is the script:

```
self.organizations = [];

Service.get(self.orgId).then(function (org) {
    self.organizations.push({
        Organization: org,
        Role: "User"
    });

    Service.getGroups().then(function (result) {
        _.forEach(result.Objects, function (res) {
            if (res.org.Id === self.orgId) {
                self.organizations.Groups = res.Groups;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

First I get data of the organization. Then inside this promise I retrieve all groups, and if a group as the same organization ID it then significates group nd organization are bound.

the res.Groups model example:

```
res.Groups = [
    {Id: 1, Name: "Group Name 1"},
    {Id: 2, Name: "Group Name 2"}
];
```

Due to other functions not showed, I can't use any other function "architecture".

I then want to add to the self.organizations array, at the index of the current organization, its groups. But the result here is that I get:

```
self.organizations = [
    {Organization: "First Organization", Role: "User"},
    {Organization: "Second Organization", Role: "User"},
    Groups: [
        {Id: 1, Name: "Group Name 1"},
        {Id: 2, Name: "Group Name 2"}
        {Id: 3, Name: "Group Name 3"}
    ]
];
```

And what I expect:

```
self.organizations = [
    {
        Organization: "First Organization",
        Role: "User",
        Groups: [
            {Id: 1, Name: "Group Name 1"},
            {Id: 1, Name: "Group Name 2"}
        ]
    },
    {
        Organization: "Second Organization",
        Role: "User",
        Groups: [
            {Id: 3, Name: "Group Name 3"}
        ]
    }
];
```

I don't know how to push the res.Groups inside the current organization (current first promise iteration). I know my structure may be improper but I struggle findind a proper working one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first add the `Groups` to the current object and then push it into the collection:

```
self.organizations = [];

Service.get(self.orgId).then(function (org) {
    var item = {
        Organization: org,
        Role: "User"
    }

    Service.getGroups().then(function (result) {
        _.forEach(result.Objects, function (res) {
            if (res.org.Id === self.orgId) {
                item.Groups = res.Groups;
            }
        });

        self.organizations.push(item);
    });
});
```